# Do you sculpt a character for a game with the clothing as one object or separate

Tags: modeling

So I'm just beginning to try character modeling out for a game and I'm currently modeling an enemy. This enemy I plan to have some different variety: same body but different clothing. Problem is I am unsure how to go about it.

Do I sculpt the enemy without clothing and then make copies of that corresponding to how many variety I want? Or can I create 1 body and then I can create clothing separately? If that's the case, how does the retopology happen? Do so for the body and for any clothing separately?

If im asking some wrong question (because of unfamiliarity), please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do it either way. However the usual approach is to have any changeable clothing be separate..

Often you wouldn't sculpt the clothing any way, because the shape of the mesh isn't important and will get deformed instead by the things under it using a simulation. As I said in my comment it's a bit complicated, so you really need to learn more about the cloth simulation system.

If you didn't want to use the simulation, either because you have very rigid clothes/armour or it's super tight against the character then I would probably model and retopo the character first plus rig it. For tight stuff, just duplicate and lift the retopoed surface from the relevant part of your character. Since it's tight fitting you can use the same bone weights for the most part and save a bunch of time.

But it all depends on what you need. For realistic clothes and armour it's best to model the body and then put the bits on of top of it. If you don't care then you could skip making any parts of the body that are fully covered.

If for example your character appears in three different sets of full plate/powered armour then you're probably better off just making three entire characters that just share a head or something. They may even need different animations if the clothing is sufficiently different.

There isn't really one right or wrong way. It's just having a base body that you can put different clothes on is more flexible and extendible, especially if they can share one animation set.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit more about your last sentence? "Often you wouldn't sculpt the clothing any way, the shape of the mesh isn't important and will get deformed instead by the things under it using a simulation". If you wouldn't sculpt, lets say a shirt, how would you do it? Just model it over the body? Also, probably unrelated, lets say you do model it separately over the body, how will that follow the work when you deform the body?

Comment: @g_b So a shirt for example could be two T shaped planes on each side of the body, joined along the appropriate edges and subdivided enough times to allow deformation. You could then add a cloth simulation to the shirt and a rigid body to your character. The simulation will update for any animations you make. It's a bit complicated, you may need to use 'pins' to attach some parts of the shirt to bones, very tight parts may not need simulation. You will need to watch/read a bunch of tutorials on cloth simulation.